# Decrease a whole column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have my "Id" column that looks like this:

```
Id
----
1
2
3
4
...
59
60
```

How do i decrease each one of them so that "Id" 20 for example will be 19 and 41 will be 40? (And so on)
Is there a mysql command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET id = id - 1
```

Comment: Hmmm, it says "Error Code: 1062 Duplicate entry '42' for key 'PRIMARY'" How to fix this???

Comment: Oh, it's a primary key... Not sure if this will work, but try `UPDATE mytable SET id = id - 1 ORDER BY id ASC`.

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
update YourTable
set id = id - 1
```